# how to stop duplicate entry in struts table after page refresh

Tags: java

I have created a table and a text box, whenever i m inserting a new value in database(also visible at page) after refresh the same value gets inserted again again in the table.

Also i have tried
to use scope="session" in my struts.XML file but it didn't solved my problem

**Java code:**

```java
connection = getConnection(); 
String query = "INSERT INTO flattype(type) VALUES('"+type+"')"; 
ps = connection.prepareStatement(query); ps.executeUpdate();


<span class="relative">
                    <sj:textfield id="flatName" name="flatName" onkeyup="fieldCompleteStatus();"
                                onkeypress="return CharacterValidation(event,this.value)" >
                                </sj:textfield>
                                </span>


  <button  type="submit" id="add-btn"  class="add-btn legend" onclick="submitform(event,'#addNewFlatType');" style="margin-left:182px;margin-right:0px; margin-top:106px;" >Submit</button>



function submitform(event,id,tid)
{
var $jq = jQuery.noConflict();

event.preventDefault();
try
{
    var arr;
    switch(id)
    {


    case'#deleteExistingflat':arr=new Array('type:required');
    break;
    case'#addNewFlatType':arr=new Array('flatName:required');
    break;

    default:alert('Please mention rules to submit');
    break;

    } 

    if(arr.length>0)
    {
        if(j_validate(id,arr))
        {        

            $jq(id).submit();
            $jq(tid).val(" ");
            return true;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("not defined");
        return false;

    }   
}
catch(e)
{
    alert(e);
}
```

}

Comment: connection = getConnection();
   String query = "INSERT INTO flattype(type) VALUES('"+type+"')";
     
   ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
    ps.executeUpdate();

Comment: The piece of code you gave is useless. Maybe it would be more interesting to have the exact context where your insert is done. When is it called? Is it in the controller or -worse- directly in the JSP?

Comment: my text box is not getting null after the value is inserted that's why after refresh duplicate value is getting added again and again